# Static function declaration without definition

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I compiled a program with several compilers and one of them complained about a static function declaration without a definition in a certain compilation unit. I wonder if the standard states anything about that. 
From my point of view, it makes sense to complain here as the function cannot be used in another compilation unit and therefore is of no use at all.

Comment: Just so I understand: There's a warning, and you agree it makes sense, but you're wondering if standard says anything about it? I don't think standard mentions what compilers should warn about.

Comment: Which compiler complained? Complained how? Post the exact compiler message including line number and filename you got from the compiler, including compiler version and compiler options alongside with the smallest reproducible source code and steps needed to reproduce the issue. We can't help that some strange compiler "complained" to you.

Comment: @domen The C standard states that the compiler must give a diagnostic message for constraint violations - that is, for clear violations of the standard. The terms "warning" and "error" don't exist in the standard though, nor does the standard say anything about potential binary output from the compiler in case of language violations.

Comment: I’d like to state for the record that I did *not* vote to close the question as “too broad” (since it isn’t). I voted to close since it’s unclear what’s being asked her, and no clarifications are forthcoming. As soon as the question is sufficiently clarified I’ll vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

A static function is only visible inside that compilation unit.

A static function *declaration* provides the prototype (name, return type and parameters) of such a function.

A static function *definition* gives the implementation of the function.

A static function that is *declared* but *not used* and has no implementation, should not cause a warning. Would it be used but not have an implementation (in that compilation unit), then it is an *error*.

```
static int NotUsed(int not_used);  // perfectly legal without implementation if not used
```

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder if the standard states anything about that.

No, standard doesn't require that:

> #### 5.1.1.3 Diagnostics
>
> 1. A conforming implementation **shall produce at least one diagnostic message** (identified in an imple-mentation-defined manner) **if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a violation
>    of any syntax rule or constraint**, even if the behavior is also explicitly specified as undefined or
>    implementation-defined. **Diagnostic messages need not be produced in other circumstances.** <sup>9)</sup>

In general, standard doesn't seem to care about issues that are not actively harmful. Unnecessary declaration doesn't prevent a construction of correct program.

> From my point of view, it makes sense to complain here as the function cannot be used in another compilation unit and therefore is of no use at all.

As you have seen, some compiler providers agree with you. But it's simply not *required* by the standard.